Issue with Animation Skipping Due to Re-rendering
I’m encountering an issue with the following code:
<TabNavigation activeIndex={activeIndex} onTabChange={(index) => setActiveIndex(index)}>
    {YoutubeData && ((YoutubeData?.length ?? 0) > 0) ? YoutubeData?.map((source, index) => (
        <TabContent
            key={source.sourceId}
            source={source}
            index={index}
            title={source.name}
        />
    )) : undefined}
</TabNavigation>

Inside TabContent, I have a component like this:
<ToggleButton enable={uploadPart?.enable ?? false} onToggle={(enable) => changeButtonStatus(enable, index, VideoType.Upload)} />

When onToggle triggers changeButtonStatus, it contains code that causes a re-render. Ideally, this should allow enough time for the animation (defined by the className):
className={`${styles.toggleBtn} ${enable ? styles.active : ''} ${disabled ? styles.disabled : ''}`}

However, the animation is not being executed as expected. To investigate, I added a console.log within the .map loop:
YoutubeData?.map((source, index) => (
    // Added console.log here
    console.log('Rendering TabContent', source),
    <TabContent
        key={source.sourceId}
        source={source}
        index={index}
        title={source.name}
    />
)) : undefined

The logs confirm that .map is re-running, which appears to recreate (re-render) the TabContent component and prevents the animation from playing.
So I want to ask is
Is the .map loop indeed causing the TabContent to be re-rendered? If so, how can I prevent this from interrupting the animation while still updating the state correctly? Are there better strategies to manage this re-render behavior?
